# How to run two forms in C++Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, tform, c++builder-xe3

It's a pleasure to share some information with you.

Excuse me, does anybody know how to have two FORMS running at the same time?

I mean, I execute a FOR clicking one BUTTON on FORM1 and set FOR's values to a LABEL on FORM2.

Here some codes in FORM1:

```
void __fastcall Form1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender){
  int i = 0;
  for (i=0;i<=10000;i++){
    Form1->Label1->Caption = i;
    Form2->Label1->Caption = i;  
  }
}
```

I just want to see this:

if.... `Form1->Label1->Caption` = 1, `Form2->Label1->Caption` has to be 1 too and so on.
FORM2 shows me just the last result, which is 10,000.

I appreciate any help.
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `Update()`:  <sup>(*)</sup>

```
void __fastcall Form1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  for(int i = 0; i <= 10000; ++i)
  {
    Form1->Label1->Caption = i;
    Form2->Label1->Caption = i;

    Form1->Label1->Update();
    Form2->Label1->Update();
  }
}
```

[Update()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Update):

> Processes any pending paint messages immediately.
>
> Call Update to force the control to be repainted before any more, possibly time-consuming,
>   processing takes place. Use Update to provide immediate feedback to the user that cannot wait
>   for the Windows paint message to arrive.
>
> Update does not invalidate the control, but simply forces a repaint of any regions that have
>   already been invalidated.

[Application->ProcessMessages()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessages) will also work, but it's not the right choice: it interrupts the execution of an application so that it can process the message queue. `ProcessMessages` can be way slower.

<sup>(*) Changed since [Remy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau)'s hint was absolutely better than the original answer (`Update` vs `ProcessMessages`)</sup>

Comment: Hello manilio,thanks for answering. I already tried this solution "ProcessMessages()" and it just works perfectly on the first form, It does not refresh the second.

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure that the `ProcessMessages()` call is inside the for loop?

Comment: Yes, you are right! my problem was that I called the Form2 with ShowModal() and it has to be called with Show().

Comment: `Application->ProcessMessages()` is not the best choice. You should use `Form1->Label1->Update()` and `Form2->Label1->Update()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You‘re right. Please post the comment as an answer and I‘ll delete mine.

Comment: @manlio: Or, you could just edit your answer to provide the right information :)

Comment: Hello Remy, Thanks a lot for you information, both cases helped me.